# Script that scans folders and creates a book for each folder?

Tags: php

I'm a photographer and here's what I'm trying to achieve:
I am trying to display more "books" like these ones one under each-other:
    http://builtbywill.com/code/booklet/

I can replicate the example given in the link above for ONE Album/book but I have 20+ albums to display in my gallery and I dont want to copy/paste 20+ times the same code and change paths 20+ times etc. So I decided to do something in php:

I have the folders say IMAGES/ALBUMS/ALBUM1 to ALBUM10

I need to scan IMAGES/ALBUM and for each ALBUM1 to ALBUMx folder found display all images like this:

And here is the code I have so far:

```
function mySlider()
{
        $album = array(
            'Asia i Marcin' => 'images/albums/asiamarcin/',
            'Aneta i Marcin' => 'images/albums/anetamercin/',
        );
        $dir = $album['Asia i Marcin'];
        //$dir = 'images/asiamarcin/';
        $scan = scandir($dir);  

        for ($i=0; $i<count($scan); $i++) {  
            if ($scan[$i] != '.' && $scan[$i] != '..') {  
            echo ' 
                    <div>
                         <img width="450" heigth="385" src="'. $dir . $scan[$i] . '" alt="'. $scan[$i] . '" /> 
                    </div> 
                ';  
            }    

        }   
}
```

it's far from perfect, so far i insert it in my html like this:

```
<div class="b-load">
    <?php mySlider(); ?>
</div>
```

And i get this:

```
 <div>
 <img width="450" heigth="385" src="images/albums/asiamarcin/asiamarcin01.jpg" alt="asiamarcin01.jpg" /> 
 </div> 
 <div>
 <img width="450" heigth="385" src="images/albums/asiamarcin/asiamarcin02.jpg" alt="asiamarcin02.jpg" /> 
 </div> 
 <div>
 <img width="450" heigth="385" src="images/albums/asiamarcin/asiamarcin03.jpg" alt="asiamarcin03.jpg" /> 
 </div>
```

Ideally I would call it like this:

```
<div class="b-load">
   <?php mySlider('ALBUM1'); ?>
</div>
....
....
<div class="b-load">
  <?php mySlider('ALBUM2'); ?>
</div>
...etc...
```

I have no idea how to do this :(
I'm not a programmer but I'd like to learn so I'd appreciate your help.
Thank you,
Alex

Answer (score 1):

This will do:

```
function mySlider($dirName)
{
    $dir = 'images/albums/' . $dirName . '/';
    $scan = scandir($dir);  

    for ($i=0; $i<count($scan); $i++) {  
        if ($scan[$i] != '.' && $scan[$i] != '..') {  
        echo ' 
                <div>
                     <img width="450" heigth="385" src="'. $dir . $scan[$i] . '" alt="'. $scan[$i] . '" /> 
                </div> 
            ';  
        }    

    }   
}
```

Comment: Thank you Gregorz. So if I understood right, when calling this in the HTML i should use mySlider(album2); - where album2 is a folder inside images/albums/ correct?

Comment: yes this should work as you have described